# How to stop for loop in HTML?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, jinja2

I'm using this list of dictionary to render on a template, I want to break forloop at the end of a specific dictionary,
If

```
test_ranking_table = [
   {
      "Team":"India",
      "Matches":"44",
      "Rating":"121",
      "points":"5313"
   },
   {
      "Team":"South Africa",
      "Matches":"39",
      "Rating":"115",
      "points":"4484"
   },
   {
      "Team":"Australia",
      "Matches":"40",
      "Rating":"104",
      "points":"4174"
   },
   {
      "Team":"New Zealand",
      "Matches":"35",
      "Rating":"100",
      "points":"3489"
   },
   {
      "date-updated":"27 January 2018",
      "match-type":"ICC Test Championship"
   }
]
```

If I do a for loop for test_ranking_table

```
<thead class="thead-inverse">
    <tr>
        <th class="bg-dark text-lg-left">TEAM</th>
        <th class="bg-dark text-lg-left">Matches</th>
        <th class="bg-dark text-lg-left">Points</th>
        <th class="bg-dark text-lg-left">Rating</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for team in test_ranking_table %}
    <tr class="table table-bordered">
    <td>{{ team["Team"]}}</td>
             <td>{{ team['Matches'] }}</td>
             <td>{{ team['points'] }}</td>
             <td>{{ team['Rating'] }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

I get a empty row of table at the end because of the different key and value of last set of dictionary `{'date-updated': '27 January 2018', 'match-type': 'ICC Test Championship'}`
so how can I break for loop before it going to last set of dictionary, so I don't get any empty table rows.

Comment: Are you creating this list of dictionaries? You might want to remove that last dictionary inside of the list because you're trying to store two different things in one list

Comment: How about just slicing: `{% for team in test_ranking_table[:-1] %}`

Comment: @schwobaseggl slicing indeed works, thanks